# Removing array elements that contain a number

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have seen several answers on Stackoverflow but none have helped me. I have a huge array of nearly 100,000 words, of which I am trying to remove all words that contain a number. I am using the following to do that:

```
    for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
      if (hasNumbers(words[i]) {
        words.splice(i, 1);
      }


   function hasNumbers(t)
      { return /\d/.test(t); }
```

It seems to work, but not all the time because I am still getting words that contain numbers. What can I change to make this remove all words that contain any number at all?

(I am using p5.js with my js)

Comment: I've never used p5, but using just pure javascript I didn't get the same error.

Comment: don't `splice` in a loop, if you can somehow avoid it. It has too much overhead. use [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead to determine wich words to keep.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had started writing this and then trincot answered. His answer is correct, though with the popular and widespread usage of ES5 array functions, I feel like you could simplify this down quite a bit.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var data = [
    'w3.org',
    'google.com',
    '00011118.com'
  ]; //This is supposed to be your data, I didn't have it so I made it up.

  var no_nums = data.filter(function(item) {
    //Tests each string against the regex, inverts the value (false becomes true, true becomes false)
    return !/\d/.test(item);
  });
  var results = document.getElementById('results');
  no_nums.forEach(function(item) {
    results.innerHTML += item + '<br />';
    //Loops through each of our new array to add the item so we can see it.
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="results">
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

That is because when you delete a word at index *i*, the next word will have index *i*, yet you still increase *i*, thereby skipping a word which you never inspect.

To solve this you can go backwards through your array:

```
for(var i = words.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    // etc.
```

Here is a shorter way to remove words with digits:

```
words = words.filter(a => !hasNumbers(a));
```

Finally, you really should call your second function *hasDigits* instead of *hasNumbers*. The words "digit" and "number" have a slightly different meaning.

Here is a snippet, using ES6 syntax, that defines the opposite function *hasNoDigits* and applies it to some sample data:

```js
let words = ['abcd', 'ab0d', '4444', '-)#', '&9µ*'];

let hasNoDigits = s => /^\D*$/.test(s);

console.log(words.filter(hasNoDigits));
```

```
words = words.filter(a => !hasNumbers(a));
```

Comment: You are a boss, thank you! It's a bummer that I didn't think it through enough.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that typo. I was just simplifying my problem in the code I shared above.

Comment: hint: `words.filter(hasNumbers)` keeps the wrong set of values, the ones containing digits. I'd use a tiny utility here: `let not = fn => v => !fn(v);` and `words.filter( not(hasNumbers) )`

Comment: Thank you @Thomas! What exactly is that `let` content? Have no idea what is going on there.

Comment: @MichaelRader `let` is a block scoped version of `var`, and the part behind that is called fat arrow `=>`, and is kind of a shorthand to write functions.

Comment: Simpler I think to do this with a while loop: `var i = words.length; while (i--) {...}`.

Comment: Indeed, the filter was doing the opposite. Updated now.